# ASIHTTPRequest Reachability How to

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest

As much as I like ASIHTTPRequest, it isn't documented anywhere how to use the modified the Reachability class, and I couldnt find it on stackoverflow, or any sample projects either.

Currently im at this point:

```
Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"http://google.com"];
[reach startNotifier];

if ([reach isReachable]) {
    NSLog(@"connection");
}else{
    NSLog(@"no connection");
}
```

Which doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `Reachability` is originally a class that was provided by Apple in their sample code, which is quite well documented in my opinion. It can be found here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set up a notification handler for this:

```
Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"http://google.com"];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:)
                                             name:kReachabilityChangedNotification
                                           object:nil];
[reach startNotifier];
```

Then, implement the handler like so:

```
- (void) reachabilityChanged:(Reachability *) reach {
    if ([reach isReachable]) {
       NSLog(@"connection");
    } else{
       NSLog(@"no connection");
    }
}
```

Also, when you don't need to know when things change, remove yourself as an observer:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
```

---

Comment: reachabilityChanged isn't being called when the reachability is actually being changed.

Comment: @MaikelS it's probably because `reach` is nil. do this:


`Reachability *reach = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"google.com"] retain];`

and add a release in dealloc or appropriate location

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void) reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    Reachability *localReachability = [notification object]; 


    if ([localReachability isReachable])

    {
        NSLog(@"connection");
    } else{
        NSLog(@"no connection");
    }
```

}

, Please make these changes then  code gonna work like a charm :)

Comment: This is actually the right handler.  If use ARC, add a property  to keep it alive.