# How to implement ASIHttpRequest Reachability

Tags: ios, asihttprequest, nsnotifications, reachability

I'm having trouble implementing the Reachability class from asihttprequest.

I followed [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472719/asihttprequest-reachability-how-to) but my selector is never implemented.  Here is my code

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ReachabilityChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[reach startNotifier];

-(void)ReachabilityChanged:(Reachability *)reach{
    if ([reach isReachable]) {
        NSLog(@"reachable");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"not reachable");
    }
}
```

I also tried `Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"http://google.com"];`

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to be retaining the `Reachability` object, so presumably the autorelease instance returned by `reachabilityForInternetConnection` will be destroyed before it has a chance to notify you of anything.